# How to cast object to ISingleResult<T> where T is interface C# 3.0

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, casting

In my program I have a function which returns object. I know that this object is `ISingleResult<T>` where T is unknown, but it implements an interface IFoo. How do I cast this object to `ISingleResult<IFoo>` using C# 3.0?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ReturnValue` property. It is defined in one of the interfaces `ISingleResult<T>` derives from.